# Backing up mongo database of about 120 GB size

Tags: mongodb, backup, mongodump

We have a mongo database of about 120 GB size. I have run `mongodump` using `nohup` and redirecting the logs to `/dev/null` about 3 days back, but the dump file is  ~40GB in size now, and the dump is still running. Is this expected?

If yes, what is the approximate compression ratio for a mongo database? i.e. for a 120 GB database, how much is the backup file size going to be?

This would help me in estimating the time remaining for the dump to finish. I have no clue why it is taking up so much time, also, wanted to know if there is a faster/better way of backing up the mongo database (remote copy is not something i'm considering)?

Comment: Offtopic. Not really a programming question. This is more DBA-related, so try the dba site.

Comment: How many collections do you have ? If you have many collections and are using version 3.0.1 check out this JIRA ticket: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/TOOLS-698

Comment: I have the same amount of data on one collection, the backup is approx. 40GB and takes (with low priority on CPU) 3 hours.

Comment: @ConstantinGuay That's actually pretty much in contrast with what's happening in my case;45GB backed up and 3 days taken!

Comment: @Jaco Thanks for the link, but i have 2.6 , so I may not be hitting that issue

Comment: @MarcB I know it's not a programming question, but found other mongodump related questions in stackoverflow and that's the reason I've used this forum

Comment: SO is ***NOT*** a forum. It is a site for asking programming related questions and – hopefully – get them answered.